# Facebook GRAPH API Bigger images in JSON response

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api

Is there a method to get bigger images from this code?

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
accessToken,
"/GAMETIMETV/feed",
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
  // Insert your code here
}
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields","name,message,created_time,link,attachments{media{image}}");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

This usually give me square images with low resolution , I need to get higher resolution maybe adding some parameters to the request.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String imageurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
```

Use this link to get image

Comment: @Niccolò Fanton Try this solution with seperate network request.

Comment: Is it possible without another request?

Comment: otherwisw i wll update my answer with my full code np